# error Element //..... not found

Tags: xpath, selenium

I got an error `[error] Element //div[@id='newslist_config']//button[@type='button'] not found` when I use auto run to run my selenium test but if I click at the command and choose `Execute this command` The tests pass. Could you tell me why selenium can not find that element?

My selenium test is

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//div[@id='newslist_config']//button[@type='button']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

The html is

```
<div id="newslist_config" class="section-box span8">
<div class="accordion-group">
<div class="accordion-heading">
<h3>News-List Configuration</h3>
<a class="btn btn-danger close_newslist_config" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">remove widget</a>
<button class="btn btn-info collapse-btn" type="button" href="#collapse_newslist" data-parent="#newslist_config" data-toggle="collapse">
<span class="edit-btn-txt">
<span class="collapse-btn-txt">
</button>
</div>
<div id="collapse_newslist" class="collapse collapse-box">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about `//div[@id='accordion-heading']/descendant::input[@type='button']`?

Answer (score 0):

You could instead try the xpath: `//div[@id='accordion-heading']/button[@type='button']`
This is a more direct path; if it does not work I would suggest trying to click one of the containing spans as sometimes, due to styling, clicking an elements span achieves more consistent results. I sometimes have this issue when working with WebDriver in KendoUI.

Comment: I change to use //div[@id='newslist_config']/div[@class='accordion-group']/div[@class='accordion-heading']/button[@type='button']  but it still doesnt work when I run with "play currently test case" But if work when I right click at the command and choose "Execute this command.

Comment: If it only works when you execute the command directly (or with a pause) you are most likely doing something wrong before or after that xpath. Might be worth looking at the surrounding areas of your code as sleeps are not great!

Answer (score 0):

Approach:

1.Derive the CSS Selector from the given DOM.

css=#newslist_config  .collapse-btn

2.Perform the click

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#newslist_config  .collapse-btn")).click();